# Only include span text than contains specific text string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to work out a way to return text in the span attribute if it contains a specific string or character in this case (':').  What I have so far is:

```
Contract = soup.find('div', {'class': 'contact-long'}).find_all('span')
Contract_Keys = [span.get_text() for span in Contract]
```

I have seen something along the lines of this but it doesn't work:

```
Contract = soup.find('div', {'class': 'contact-long'}).find_all('span')
Contract_Keys = [span.get_text() for span in Contract if span.get_text() == ":"]
```

Does it need some sort of wildcat character (like '*:*') to make it work? Cheers in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be you just need to do

```
if ":" in span.get_text()
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also thanks to @holloway for showing how it fits into my line of code! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted is probably to check `":" in span.get_text()` instead of `span.get_text() == ":"`.

But what you can do is to use regex and `text` parameter of `.find`/`findAll`:

```
import re
contracts = soup.findAll('span', text=re.compile('.*:.*'))
```

Comment: A much nicer solution. In this case I think it needs to be `soup.find('div').findAll(...)` to match OP's use case.

Comment: @MarkoManenica, try `[span.get_text() for span in Contract if ':' in span.get_text()]`.

Comment: Thanks @yevhen.  It worked using:             `Contract = soup.find('div', {'class': 'contact-long'}).find_all('span', text=re.compile('.*:.*'))`

Comment: I am also trying to write a version where the find_all is first and then use just a normal find but I can't get it to work:  `Details = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'list-desc'}).find('span', text=re.compile('.*:.*'))`  Any suggestions?

Comment: `find_all` returns a list doesn't it? What about something like `[tag.find('span', text=re.compile('.*:.*')) for tag in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'list-desc'})]`?

Comment: @Holloway that would produce `None`  for each `div` that does not have `span` that matches text regex. So would produce something like `[None, 'text:text', None, None, 'other:text']`. My post is just an idea on how to solve this. OP can adjust it to his needs.